# How to visualize filters after the 1st layer trained by CNNs?

Tags: conv-neural-network

The filters at the 1st stage of the CNN can be easily visualized since they are of depth 3 (RGB). How do I visualize the later ones ? Like in http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/winter1516_lecture7.pdf

[image]

If the 2nd stage filter has depth more than 3, how can i visualize it like in the figure above ? Is it still in RGB or ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, those pictures can be generated with a method from [zeilerECCV2014 paper](https://cs.nyu.edu/~fergus/papers/zeilerECCV2014.pdf), given a pre-trained network and an image dataset. It is done in two steps:

1. pick images from a dataset that give strongest response.
2. using backpropagation, generate minimal input images that would give that same response. Those minimal images are those in your picture.

Here are the code examples for Tensorflow that I've seen to work.

- [TF-Visualize-CNN](http://github.com/kukuruza/TF-Visualize-CNN) implements only step (1)
- [tf_cnnvis](https://github.com/InFoCusp/tf_cnnvis) implements both steps.